# Css Transform skew the edges

Tags: html, css

Good morning all,
I want to make skew the edges in my menu similarly this: 
[image]

I tried to set the `li` `first child` and `last-child` pseudo class css.. my code: http://www.bootply.com/9sOm7siHNT

How to implement it?

Comment: Instead of giving `background-color: #000` to your `UL` tag, give that background color to your `li` tags. It would work. 
And after that if you see black color on your first `li`, go to css and delete it's `:before` property.

Comment: @DeepakYadav Yess.. i give that background to `li` and add `margin-left:-1px;` and all OK! Thank you )

Comment: Added it as an answer. You can mark as answer and close the question now

Comment: @DeepakYadav Are you here? Need your help man

Comment: Yep.  I'm here.  share your issue in detail

Comment: @DeepakYadav I need help with `backgraund-attachment: fixed` :( one minute i explain in detail

Comment: @DeepakYadav See this link please http://new-help.2d.uz/example/textile/index.html when i scroll, my 2 backgrounds (logo and girl) POPs up down.. i don't know why... but when i start firebug and started change css, his show normal =( but must be show that http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/16/1012/h_1476257963_5609641_3b83b9993b.jpg

Comment: you have given `fixed` value inside your `background` property. . `background-attachment: fixed;` makes your image fixed when scrolled. hence this effect is occuring.

Comment: @DeepakYadav I know about `background-attachment` but he fixed immediately and image fast down... i don't know why.. can you say me how would you write this effect http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/16/1012/h_1476257963_5609641_3b83b9993b.jpg  in my example  please..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125475/discussion-between-deepak-yadav-and-tristar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of giving `background-color: #000` to your `UL` tag, give that background color to your `li` tags.

```css
.main_menu .navbar-header {} .main_menu .navbar-toggle {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.main_menu .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.main_menu .navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.main_menu .navbar-nav li {
  background-color: #000;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  /* SKEW */
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
.main_menu .navbar .navbar-nav li:first-child:before {
  left: -13px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 26px;
  height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
.main_menu .navbar-nav li a {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  transform: skew(20deg);
}
.main_menu .navbar-nav li:after {
  content: '|';
  position: absolute;
  color: #333;
  left: 0;
  top: 5px;
  transform: skew(20deg);
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: -999;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: 0.1s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s;
  transition: 0.1s;
}
/*.main_menu .navbar-nav li:first-child {`
 transform: skew(-20deg);
 background-color: #000;
}*/

.main_menu .navbar-nav .active,
.main_menu .navbar-nav li:hover,
.main_menu .nav>li:focus {
  background-color: #067bbe;
}
.main_menu .navbar-nav li:hover:after,
.main_menu .navbar-nav li:hover+li:after {
  content: '';
}
.main_menu .nav>li>a:hover,
.main_menu .nav>li>a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.main_menu .navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="main_menu">
  <nav class="navbar navbar_main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_menu" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">ХРОНОЛОГИЯ <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">ПРОИЗВОДСТВО</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">БРЕНДЫ</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">ВАКАНСИИ</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">ОТЗЫВЫ</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">КОНТАКТЫ</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">FASHION БЛОГ</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
```